# grep for expression containing variable

Tags: bash

I want to add this command **grep -co '\b5\b' $INFILE** in a bash script. The problem is that instead of 5 i want to use a variable in its place so i write:

```
V=`grep -co '\b$L\b' $INFILE`
```

but it does not work since the $ is used to describe internally the end of line in grep. How can i make it work? Is there an escape sequence for $ to make it use its bash meaning of the value of a variable?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `"` instead of `'` to allow expansion of your `$L` variable.

Comment: For reference, http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Single-Quotes (And the section below, which is Double-Quotes)

Comment: Also, inside double quotes if you do want to specify end-of-line, escape the dollar sign `grep "foo\$"` (although that's not strictly necessary if there's nothing but a quote after the dollar sign).

Answer (score 0):

I regularly encounter this issue: accurately using `grep` or `rg` (`ripgrep`) to find `$variables`.

Conclusion (best practice, based on following experiments):

- Use single quotes, and \-escape the $

  `'\$variable'`

  not

  `"\$variable'` or unescaped `"$variable"`

```bash
## ----------------------------------------
[victoria@victoria]$ which grep
  /usr/bin/grep

[victoria@victoria]$ grep --version
  grep (GNU grep) 3.7
  ...

[victoria@victoria]$ which rg
  /usr/bin/rg

[victoria@victoria]$ rg --version
  ripgrep 13.0.0
  ...

[victoria@victoria]$

## ----------------------------------------
## RIPGREP (rg):
## -------------

## ----------------------------------------
## -i : ignore case
## -n : show matching lines, line numbers
## -l : show matching files
## -R : search recursively (grep)

## TRUE: 8 files matching '\$username':
[victoria@victoria]$ rg * --color=always -il -e '\$username' | wc -l
  8

## TRUE: In those 8 files, 34 lines matching '\$username':
[victoria@victoria]$ rg * --color=always -in -e '\$username' | wc -l
  34

## First 5 matching lines:
[victoria@victoria]$ rg * --color=always -in -e '\$username' | head -n5

  sql/old/mysql-pg_auth-create_tables-2022.05.28.php:13:$username = "root";

  sql/old/mysql-pg_auth-create_tables-2022.05.28.php:25:
  $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);

  sql/old/mysql-pg_auth-create_tables-2022.05.28.php:58:
  $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);

  src/auth.php:23:* @param string $username

  src/auth.php:36:function register_user(string $email, string $username, 
  string $password, string $activation_code, int $expiry = 1 * 24  * 60 *
  60, bool $is_admin = false): bool

## ----------------------------------------
## single quotes, unescaped $ - no matching lines
## (FALSE - there are 34 lines matching: $username):
[victoria@victoria]$ rg * --color=always -in -e '$username' | wc -l
  0

## ----------------------------------------
## double quotes, \-escaped $ - no matching files
## (FALSE - there are 8 files matching: $username):
[victoria@victoria]$ rg * --color=always -il -e "\$username" | wc -l
  0

## ----------------------------------------
## FALSE - as shown in following query ...
[victoria@victoria]$ rg * --color=always -il -e "$username" | wc -l
  154

## ... unescaped "$username" falsely matching lines:
[victoria@victoria]$ rg * --color=always -in -e "$username" | head -n5

  vendor/autoload.php:1:<?php
  vendor/autoload.php:2:
  vendor/autoload.php:3:// autoload.php @generated by Composer
  vendor/autoload.php:4:
  vendor/autoload.php:5:if (PHP_VERSION_ID < 50600) {

[victoria@victoria]$

## ----------------------------------------
## GREP
## ----

## grep is somewhat more forgiving:

## unquoted variable name (misses matches;
## should be 8 matching files):
[victoria@victoria]$ grep --color=always -ilR $username * | wc -l
  3

## "$username" - FALSE (way too many files):
[victoria@victoria]$ grep --color=always -ilR "$username" * | wc -l
  442

## '$username' - TRUE number of matched files:
[victoria@victoria]$ grep --color=always -ilR '$username' * | wc -l
  8

[victoria@victoria]$ grep --color=always -inR '$username' * | head -n5

  docs-private/_readme-victoria.txt:159: function register_user(string 
  $email, string $username, string $password, string $activation_code,
  int $expiry = 1 * 24  * 60 * 60, bool $is_admin = false): bool

  docs-private/_readme-victoria.txt:166:
  $statement->bindValue(':username', $username);

  sql/create_drop_mysql_tables.php:20:$username = "root";

  sql/create_drop_mysql_tables.php:35:    $conn = new 
  PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);

  sql/create_drop_mysql_tables.php:72:    $conn = new 
  PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);

## '\$username' - TRUE number of matched files:
[victoria@victoria]$ grep --color=always -ilR '\$username' * | wc -l
  8

## "\$username" = TRUE number of matched files:
[victoria@victoria]$ grep --color=always -ilR "\$username" * | wc -l
  8
```