# GREP: variable in regular expression

Tags: regex, bash, grep

If I want to look whether a string is alphanumeric and shorter than a certain value, say 10, I would do like this (in BASH+GREP):

`if grep '^[0-9a-zA-Z]\{1,10\}$' <<<$1 ; then ...`

(BTW: I'm checking for $1, i.e. the first argument)

What if I want the value 10 to be written on a variable, e.g.

```
UUID_LEN=10
if grep '^[0-9a-zA-Z]\{1,$UUID_LEN\}$' <<<$1 ; then ...
```

I tried all sort of escapes, braces and so on, but could not avoid the error message

```
grep: Invalid content of \{\}
```

After googling and reading bash and grep tutorials I'm pretty convinced it can't be done. Am I wrong? Any way to go around this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add grep command to bash script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142729/add-grep-command-to-bash-script)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use double quotes so that the shell expands the parameter before passing the resulting argument to `grep`:

```
if grep "^[0-9a-zA-Z]\{1,$UUID_LEN\}$" <<<$1 ; then ...
```

`bash` can perform regular expression matching itself, without having to start another process to run `grep`:

```
if [[ $1 =~ ^[0-9a-zA-Z]{1,$UUID_LEN}$ ]]; then
```

Comment: Of course! The answer was so simple! The inverted commas " " will do the trick as differently from ' ' they expand what's inside... the answer. Thanks