# TCL : How to use variable inside grep in exec

Tags: tcl

How can i use variable inside grep in exec in TCL

```
"^STRING__${abc}__STRING__${abc}\[\[:space:\]\]*="
```

Tried Ways,

```
exec grep "^STRING__${abc}__STRING__${abc}\[\[:space:\]\]*="
exec grep {^STRING__${abc}__STRING__${abc}\[\[:space:\]\]*=}
exec grep {{^STRING__${abc}__STRING__${abc}\[\[:space:\]\]*=}}
```

Tried this above solutions, but not able to execute properly.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I take it that your `grep` requires the brackets to be escaped? The first Way above will strip away the backslashes, and the second and third won't substitute the variable.

The easiest way to do this is probably to use `format`:

```
set regex [format {^STRING__%1$s__STRING__%1$s\[\[:space:\]\]*=} $abc]
exec grep $regex
```

The principle of it is to write the regex string as you want it to be inside the braces and replace the variable occurrences with `%s` specifiers, or `%1$s` to put the same string in more than one place, add the string to be inserted and call `format` on it.

If you don't need the backslashes after all, it's safe to remove them from the `format` string (as long as the braces are in place around it).

Documentation: [format](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/format.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm)

Comment: FYI: As of today, i was able to follow @David W. answer to a similar Question: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18147884/shell-variable-in-a-grep-regex
That solved the problem by double-quoting the variable that contains the regex.