# Using variable in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-$variable

Tags: bash

```
grep ^IPADDR= /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-$devicename
```

Can i just do $devicename without any brackets? Because I'm having using a head -1 to read off the first line of the file which will than be append to the $devicename. But when I run it, it says grep: enp0s3: No such file or directory or grep: lo: No such file or directory

Comment: possible duplicate of [grep for expression containing variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142729/grep-for-expression-containing-variable)

Comment: your variable $devicename probably has a space at the start.