# How to use sed and egrep in bash shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, command-line

I am writing a bash shell script in which I want to use two shell commands `sed` and `egrep`.

My bash shall script read a text file `q2.txt` and then do some actions using `egrep` and `sed`.

The code is as given below.

```
#!/bin/bash
var=$(<q2.txt)

sed "s/^[ \t]*//" -i var
grep -v '^/\*.*\*/$' var
echo "$var"
```

I read the content of `q2.txt` in variable `var`. Then remove the tabs and spaces using sed `s/^[ \t]*//" -i var` and update my `var`.

Then execute `grep -v '^/\*.*\*/$' var` on my updated variable to select some lines with specific start and end.

But in the ouput, It seems like `grep` and `sed` are not applicable to `var`.

```
Output
sed: can't read var: No such file or directory
grep: var: No such file or directory
```

Comment: `var` is treated as a filename by  sed and grep... but there's no reason to try to read a file into a shell variable for this. Have you heard of piping one processes output into another processes input?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [shell variable in a grep regex](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18147884/608639), [grep for expression containing variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5142729/608639), etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a much simpler approach

```
cat q2.txt | sed "s/^[ \t]*//" | grep -v '^/\*.*\*/$'
```

Comment: Your grep regular expression isn't equivalent to the OP's. (Though who knows if his was what he actually wants...)

Comment: Um - I cut and pasted it.  In what way do you think it differs?

Comment: Yours didn't escape the asterisks and I think was missing stuff. Looks like it was fixed in an edit though.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is more about shell variables, rather than sed/grep.

See:

- https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html
- http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe

Also better to use the Pipe (`|`) as the other answer has showed, so you don't have to store the intermediate result.